# How to map json object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have json:

```
{
  "userList":
  [{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 28
  },{
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 45
  },{
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 32
  }]
}
```

I want to cut only age and put them to array like : public mainChartData1: Array = [28, 45, 32];

I have started to do that by next code:

```
  const arr = this.users.map(obj => {

    var localObj = [];
      localObj[obj] = obj.age;
      return localObj;

    });
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a little map function to extract the array age

```js
const inputObject = {
  "userList":
  [{
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 28
  },{
    "name": "Tom",
    "age": 45
  },{
    "name": "Alice",
    "age": 32
  }]
  };
  
  const output = inputObject.userList.map(user => user.age);
  console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 4):

Say `arrayObject` is the object you have, following should do it. `map` will return a new array that will be assigned to `ageArray`.

```
let ageArray = arrayObject.userList.map(e => e.age)
```